# intellij Idea javafx export can't build artifact-fx:deploy is not available

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, export, executable-jar

I have spent so many hours on searching for methods to export javafx from intellij, but they all did not end up working. I have tried using maven and a few other methods but they all did not work. 
[image]

[image]

[image]

these are some of my settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, Oracle just made the deployment of JavaFX files harder in more recent JDK versions.

1) The easiest way is to set JDK 8 on your project: File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK

2) The harder way is to choose jar file (not JavaFx Application) and then follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGHu-SzL-5E or https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx

3) And the last way is to use Gradle: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle

Comment: no link-only answers, even it's only a part of the answer :) Instead summarize what's shown there and keep the reference for those who want to see for themselves